# Jacobian of an inverse

Tags: calculus, matrices, transformation

Suppose that we have an invertible map $T(u,v)=(x,y)$.
The Jacobian of $T$ is given by

$
   \text{Jac}(T)=
  \left| {\begin{array}{cc}
   x_u & x_v \\
   y_u & y_v \\
  \end{array} } \right|$.

Now if we consider the inverse map of $T$, i.e. $T^{-1}(x,y)=(u,v)$, its Jacobian is given by

$
   \text{Jac}(T^{-1})=
  \left| {\begin{array}{cc}
   u_x & u_y \\
   v_x & v_y \\
  \end{array} } \right|$.

Since $H=TT^{-1}=I$ is the mapping $H(u,v)=(u,v)$, we expect that

$
   \text{Jac}(H)=
  \left| {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right|$.

I know that $1=\frac{du}{du}=\frac{dv}{dv}$ and that $0=\frac{du}{dv}=\frac{dv}{du}$ but I cannot seem to figure out how multiplying the two matrices above would give the identity matrix. Doesn't look like the right chain rule to me...any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: It is *precisely* the correct statement of the chain rule that gives you that the product of the two matrices is the identity matrix (hence of the Jacobian determinants is $1$). We're working with partial derivatives here. And remember that $x=x(u,v)$, $y=y(u,v)$, etc., are functions, not just variables.

Comment: I'm sorry but do you mind to be more explicit about it?

Comment: sorry, i got it now. thanks!

Comment: $$\small\begin{align}TT^{-1} &=\begin{bmatrix}x_u & x_v\\y_u & y_v\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u_x & u_y\\v_x & v_y\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}x_uu_x+x_vv_x & x_uu_y+x_vv_y\\y_uu_x+y_vv_x & y_uu_y + y_vv_y\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}x_x & x_y\\y_x & y_y\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5):

The multivariable chain rule is not normally stated in terms of strange things like $\frac{dv}{du}$. It is stated in terms of total derivatives, i.e.,  linear transformations that approximate the map at a given point. In particular, it says that if $T(u_0,v_0)=(x_0,y_0)$, then the derivative of the composition $T^{-1}\circ T$ at $(u_0,v_0)$ is the composition of the derivative of $T$ at $(u_0,v_0)$ and the derivative of $T^{-1}$ at $(x_0,y_0)$. The composition $T^{-1}\circ T$ is the identity map, so its derivative is also the identity map. 
Conclusion: the derivative of $T^{-1}$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ is the inverse of the derivative of $T$ at $(u_0,v_0)$. This can be expressed in matrices if one wishes.